# Which network protocol is used for media streaming from online music or video sites?

Tags: layer3, transport-protocol, streaming

I would like to know which network protocols are used for media streaming by online music and video sites ?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, as currently stated your question is too broad to be answered. Either it has too many possible answers or a good answer would be too long for this format. Please edit your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. Not every site/service is going to necessarily use the same protocols. So which sites? How are the streams accessed (browser, app, etc)?

Comment: His question is not too broad to be answered.  As you can see below, I answered in using only 37 words.

Answer (score 0):

If by music and video sites, you mean web servers you can access with a web browser, then the protocol in use is the one you see at the beginning of the URL within your web browser, ex.:

```
https://www.spotify.com/
```

. It is plain HTTP (i.e. 80/tcp) or HTTPS (i.e. 443/tcp).

Answer (score 0):

There are many network protocols at play.  Some at the network layer (IP), some at the transport layer (TCP / UDP).  Then there are formats or codecs for the media such as mp3 and mp4 and webm.